# Relation between test and train error with gradient descent iterates

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, gradient-descent, risk, training-error

My question is about establishing an inequality between population error and expected training error (i.e, expected training error < population error) for a model trained with gradient descent on a specific loss (not necessarily until convergence).

Assume we have training data $(X,Y) = \{(x_1,y_1), \ldots, (x_n,y_n)\}$ sampled i.i.d. from an unknown distribution $P$. Say we do ERM with a loss function $\ell$ and obtain $\hat f = \arg\min_{f\in\mathcal{F}} \frac{1}{n}\sum_i \ell(f(x_i),y_i)$. With $f^*$, we denote the true minimizer of the population loss. From basic ERM inequality, we have
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_i \ell(\hat f(x_i),y_i) \le \frac{1}{n}\sum_i \ell(f^*(x_i),y_i)\,.$$
Taking expectation on both sides, we have
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{n}\sum_i \ell(\hat f(x_i),y_i)\right] \le \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{n}\sum_i \ell(f^*(x_i),y_i)\right]\,.$$

Elaborating, my question is about obtaining a similar inequality with a model $\tilde f_t$ obtained after taking $t$ gradient steps to minimize the same loss, i.e., $\frac{1}{n}\sum_i \ell(f(x_i),y_i)$ with a learning rate $\eta$.

Comment: Very interesting but hard question. The premise of the given inequality is that you have already obtained $\hat f$. During the procedure of optimizing, especially when you have dependency on $t$, factors like the convexity of $l$, optimizing strategies, the population distribution all join the party. Also look forward to thoughts on this.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. For simplicity, we can assume $\ell$ is convex in parameters. For example, will this hold for a linear regression problem where $\ell$ is MSE?